# PYSNMP agent returns new line characters as output after decoding of Hexa values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

Facing a strange issue with the pysnmp agent return value. 
  PYSNMP Agent receives the string format as `"0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a"`. 
  In the MIB,  OID is represented as HEXA STRING.
  When tried to return the string using `rfc1902.OctetString(hexValue=str_temp)`, the output is blank because the hexavalue `(0a0a0a)` is decoded as new lines`(\n)` characters.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::example.154.12.1.0 = STRING: "

"
```

### Pseudo code:

```
str="0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a"
After Return using rfc1902.OctetString(str) or rfc1902.OctetString(hexaValue=str)
```

**Excepted Output:**

```
SNMPv2-SMI::example.154.12.1.0 = Hex-STRING: 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A 0A
```

Can some one help me, how to decode or send the raw output to hexa string to get desired output as mentioned above.

Comment: Doesn't it have a particular definition or a particular character in the MIB definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for oid, val in varBinds:
    print(oid.prettyPrint(),' = ',val.prettyPrint())
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! A link to the docs and an explanation as to what PrettyPrinting is would improve this answer :)

Comment: I am looking for an answer that When SNMP agent sends the response as hexa value of 0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a  and the output showing is empty because of "\n" characters. How do i get the same hexa string output  from PYSNMP agent